# Linq to SQL - Multiple where clauses at runtime

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, where-clause, dynamic-linq

I am trying to accomplish this but only my first where clause is getting used when the query runs.

This needs to for for .Net 3.5 so the WhereIf in 4.0 is not usable.

```
var query =
    from tb in dataContext.TableOne
    where tb.DateTimeCreated >= fromDate && 
        tb.DateTimeCreated <= toDate.AddDays(1) 
    select tb;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reference))
{
    query.Where(tb => tb.Reference = reference));
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `query.Where(tb => tb.Reference == reference);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reference))
        query = query.Where(tb => tb.Reference = reference));
```

Comment: @veggerby & Ives. thanks guys you fixed me, I see that my mistake was not assigning my where clause back to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try

Just do it in "one"

```
var query = (from tb in dataContext.TableOne
                      where (tb.DateTimeCreated >= fromDate && tb.DateTimeCreated <= toDate.AddDays(1)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reference) || tb.Reference == reference)
                      select tb
               );
```

or as Ives says, do:

```
query = query.Where(...)
```

Comment: If you do it in "one" and that query gets sent to the database with inert parts, the query optimizer won't be able to tell which parts are inert.  It will generate a bad query plan.